# A proof of the derivative of indefinite integral of a function being the function itself

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

> Let $a<d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f:[a,d]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a
> continuous function. Suppose for each $b\leq c\in[a,d]$ we are able to
> associate a number $I^c_b(f)$ satisfying the following:
>
> 1. If $M,m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $m\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in[b,c]$, then $$m(c-b)\leq I^c_b(f)\leq M(c-b).$$
> 2. $I_a^c(f)=I_a^b(f)+I^c_b(f)$.
>
> Then the function $x\mapsto I^x_a(f)$ is differentiable on $[a,d]$ and
> its derivative is $f$.

The proof proceeds as follows:

> We have the Newton quotient, say $h>0$,
> $$\frac{I^{x+h}_{a}(f)-I_a^{x}(f)}{h}=\frac{I^x_a(f)+I^{x+h}_{x}(f)-I_a^{x}(f)}{h}=\frac{I_x^{x+h}(f)}{h}.$$
> Let $s,t$ be points in $[x, x+h]$ where $f$ reaches a minimum and
> maximum, respectively. Let $m=f(s)$ and $M=f(t)$. Then by property (1)
> $$f(s)(x+h-x)\leq I^{x+h}_x(f)\leq f(t)(x+h-x)$$ whence  $$f(s)h\leq
>  I^{x+h}_x(f)\leq f(t)h.$$ Dividing by $h$ shows that
> $$f(s)\leq\frac{I^{x+h}_x(f)}{h}\leq f(t).$$ As $h\rightarrow 0$, we
> see that $s,t\rightarrow x$, and since $f$ is continuous, by squeezing
> process, we conclude that the limit of the Newton quotient exists and
> is equal to $f(x)$.

Can someone explain why as $h\rightarrow 0$ we get $s,t\rightarrow x$? We can, e.g., rewrite $f(s)$ as $\max_{z\in[x,x+h]}f(z)$. Then the statement becomes equivalent to
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\max_{z\in[x,x+h]}f(z)=f(x).$$
Why does the above hold? How can I go about proving it?

Comment: By hypothesis, $s,t\in[x,x+h]$ so $x\leq s\leq x+h$ and $x\leq t\leq x+h$.

Comment: What book is this from?